# Using record attribute value in uniqueness validation conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check uniqueness of record attribute only for 3 months before this record `created_at`, something like:

```
validates :number, uniqueness: { conditions: -> { where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 3.months)}}
```

But instead of `Time.now` I'd like to use validated record `created_at` value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote should already work, expect if you need the opposite.

You can refactor a bit though, create a `scope` to define all items created within 3 months.

```
scope :created_within_three_month, -> { where('created_at <= ?', 3.months.ago) }
```

Then your `validates` was well written.

```
validates :number, uniqueness: true, conditions: :created_within_three_month
```

**Note**: But If I were you, I'd create a `state` on you model, then write a rake task that put on `archived` all records older than 3 months.

Then I will validates on:

```
validates :number, uniqueness: true, conditions: -> { where.not(state: 'archived') }
```